# Save the Data in Database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I am trying to save the data in data base. Whatever data user enters it has to save in database and it has to save in page it self also. when user opens page that data has to display.

code for uploading the data in database..

```
public static void sqlUploadContactInfoData(string[] Userdata)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = DBConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    string spName = "sp_testSample";  //stored procedure
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CnctNum", Userdata[0].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AltCnctNum", Userdata[1].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmerCnctNum", Userdata[2].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrsnEmail", Userdata[3].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfsEmail", Userdata[4].ToString());
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    ErrorMsg("Server Error", "Server Error ! Please try again Later.");
                }
            }
        }
```

For this I have created Stored Procedure in sql server.

Here is the stored procedure code,

```
GO // Stored Procedure
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_testSample]
@CnctNum varchar(15),
@AltCnctNum varchar(15),
@EmerCnctNum varchar(15),
@PrsnEmail varchar(25),
@OfsEmail varchar(50)

as
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Sample
           ([Contact_Num]
           ,[Alt_Contact_Num]
           ,[Emr_Contact_Num]
           ,[Per_Email]
           ,[Ofs_Email])

        VALUES
           (@CnctNum
           ,@AltCnctNum
           ,@EmerCnctNum
           ,@PrsnEmail
           ,@OfsEmail)

    END

Here I am assigning the values to the Button action..
protected void btnContactInfoSave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkContactUpdate.Checked)
            {
                string[] ContactInfoData = new string[6];
                ContactInfoData[0] = GlobalVars.UserEmail;
                ContactInfoData[1] = txtCnct.Text;
                ContactInfoData[2] = txtAltCnct.Text;
                ContactInfoData[3] = txtEmrCnct.Text;
                ContactInfoData[4] = txtPrsnEmail.Text;
                ContactInfoData[5] = txtOfsEmail.Text;
                Utilities.sqlUploadContactInfoData(ContactInfoData);
            }
        }

Here I am calling the action through button..

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align" runat="server" onserverclick="btnContactInfoSave_click" formmethod="get">

When I click the "Save" button it not saving the data and it showing the error..
In the below code it is showing error like Null exception...
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code


public static void ErrorMsg(string ErrorHeading, string ErrorMsgStr)
        {
            string errorMsgScript = "alert('"+ErrorMsgStr+"');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(null, null, ErrorHeading, errorMsgScript, true);
        }
```

In the above ErrorMsg, I am getting Null exception. I have debug the code and data is coming perfectly to the each and every field.. 
Any error in Stored Procedure code or Save action code..??
when I click the button error is coming like this,

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code

What is the issue in above all code..??

Comment: which line shows you the error message?

Comment: what does `ContactInfoData[0] = GlobalVars.UserEmail;` this line returns ?
You are passing it to `0 index` in your code and when calling uyou are using it as `@CnctNum` which I guess your `1st index` debug and see what value your getting at `0 index`

Comment: tht line is for the User's email ID. With that Email ID only he can login into portal and he can update

Comment: @kirann: where you are defining `GlobalVars.UserEmail;` when will you assign value to that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your are passing `array string` with `6 index` and using wrong sequence may be the cause of your issue, Replace below in your code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CnctNum", Userdata[1].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AltCnctNum", Userdata[2].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmerCnctNum", Userdata[3].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrsnEmail", Userdata[4].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfsEmail", Userdata[5].ToString());
```

Comment: but it is saving only in database. Not saving in Page it self. I dont want empty page when user opens the page

Comment: what are you using to store data in page? Please modify or put another question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(null, null, ErrorHeading, errorMsgScript, true);
```

You can't call RegisterClientScriptBlock without the first two parameters. It should be something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), ErrorHeading, errorMsgScript, true);
```